# Flutter: AnimatedOpacity Checkbox why I can still clik it even it is not visible

Tags: dart, flutter

I was wondering why I can still able to click or tap the checkbox even when it is not visible. It still gives print values in my console.

```
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedOpacity(
        opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        child: Checkbox(
          value: this.folder[index].checked,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
              print(value);
              setState(() {
              this.folder[index].checked = value;
              });
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Opacity Doesn't remove the Widget from the Widget Tree or disable it - it simply affects visibility of it. If You want to disable the checkbox give `value: null` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your Widget has opacity it has user interaction, so to solve your problem you have two options:

Add a condition inside `onChanged` method

```
   Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: Checkbox(
                      value: this.folder[index].checked,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        if (_visible) {
                          print(value);
                          setState(() {});
                        }
                      },
                    ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Or add a condition to display an empty `Widget` if the `_visible` variable is false

```
    Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            AnimatedOpacity(
              opacity: _visible ? 1.0 : 0.0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
              child: _visible
                  ? Checkbox(
                      value: this.folder[index].checked,
                      onChanged: (bool value) {
                        if (_visible) {
                          print(value);
                          setState(() {});
                        }
                      },
                    )
                  : SizedBox(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```